# i want to delete a specific text line from my text editor using imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am a newbie in imacros. I use imacros for firefox and imacros own browser. I want to delete extracted text line from my web page.

Problem is that it is in mid of all texts but advantage is the text which i want to delete does not changes.

I am able to extract the text line but unable to delete it.
I have used eval command with replace but nothing worked out.

I am using latest version of firefox and latest plugins of imacros.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=STRONG ATTR=TXT:Please<SP>feel<SP>free<SP>to<SP>contact<SP>us<SP>anytime<SP>@<SP>+91-22-40149634<SP>or<SP>write<SP>us<SP>info@spsat*
TAG POS=77 TYPE=P ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
```

Now I have extracted the line but dont know how to replace it with nothing or delete that line from there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that my idea will be more relevant to the described problem. Below is an example of how you can remove a certain text from the html page:

```
URL GOTO=http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET textToRemove "iMacros for Firefox"
SET textXpath "//span[text()='{{textToRemove}}']"

' just to highlight this text '
TAG XPATH={{textXpath}} EXTRACT=TXT
WAIT SECONDS=2
' ...and remove it '
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.evaluate("{{textXpath}}",document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML="";undefined;}
```

The macro should work in 'iMacros for Firefox' v. 8.9.7 (and perhaps, in 'iMacros for Chrome').